# All derivatives of the holomorphic function $g(z)$ vanish at $z=0 \implies g\equiv 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, lebesgue-measure, characteristic-functions

I apologice in advance if this question is too trivial.
Let $\nu$ be the standard gaussian measure and $f\in L^2_{\nu}(\mathbb R)$.

Let
\begin{equation}
g(z)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{i x z} f(x)\nu(d x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{i x z} f(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx
\end{equation}

How can I see the following implication ?

> All derivatives of the holomorphic function $g(z)$ vanish at $z=0$
>   implies that $g\equiv 0$.

At first I tried thinking of $g$ as the characteristic function of a r.v. whose distribution has density $f(x)e^{-x^2/2}$ wrt the Lebesgue measure, but we don't know whether $f$ is positive or not.

Can you give me some hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is independent of your specific function $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is holomorphic in a neigborhood of $0$, then $$g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n,$$
and $a_n=\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.$ If all derivatives vanished at $0$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n$. Therefore $g=0$ in a neigborhood of $0$. Using the [analytic continuation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) yields that $g=0$ on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I know barely anything about complex analysis, expressing the function as a MacLaurin series seems straightforward. The analytic continuation was, at least for me, not so immediate.